# how to open a panel with new folder function by NSOpenPanel?

Tags: cocoa

By default , we use the NSOpenPanel class method to  open a open panel:
-beginSheetForDirectory:file:types:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo: 
But I find that some software can open the open panel with new folder button , inculde the XCode , how to get it ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

Since [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inherits from [NSSavePanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSavePanel), you can use NSSavePanel's `setCanCreateDirectories` method, like the following:

```
    // Show an 'Open' dialog box allowing save folder selection.
    NSOpenPanel *open = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [open setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    [open setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [open setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [open setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
    [open setTitle:@"Open Panel Title"];
    [open setPrompt:@"Select Button Title"];
```

Back in OS X 10.2.x days, there was a private method, `_setIncludeNewFolderButton`, that did the same thing, but it was removed in Panther. Don't try using it—your app will crash.

Answer (score 2):

Swift:

```
    let picker = NSOpenPanel()
    picker.canCreateDirectories = true
    picker.runModal()
```